# Pandas Dataframe: search for specific columns, delete rows within the columns that equal a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write a piece of code and I keep getting stuck with an issue of trying to search for a list of columns in a dataframe, which is not allowed because the list is unhashable.

Essentially, I have a sequence: 'KGTLPK'
I want to first locate every instance of 'K' in the sequence: [0,5]
Then I want to search columns 0 and 5 of my DataFrame for a specific value: 80
I want to get a list of rows that have '80' in columns 0 & 5, and delete those rows.

```
query = 'KGTLPK'
AA = 'K'

x = []
for pos,char in enumerate(query):
    if(char == AA):
        x.append(pos)
print(x)
#pddf = my DataFrame
df2 = pddf.filter(regex=x)
print(df2)

rows_removal = list(pddf.loc[pddf[df2] == Phosphorylation].index.tolist())
print(rows_removal)

pddf.drop(pddf.index[rows_removal])
```

My full DataFrame has 8855 rows, and this needs to decrease as improper values are identified. In this example I deleted all rows where column 0 was not equal to 16. I just need an easier way to do this so I don't hardcode everything.

`pddf.head(10).to_dict()`  output, dataFrame unedited:

```
{0: {0: 16, 1: 16, 2: 16, 3: 16, 4: 16, 5: 16, 6: 16, 7: 16, 8: 16, 9: 16}, 1: {0: 16, 1: 16, 2: 16, 3: 16, 4: 16, 5: 16, 6: 16, 7: 16, 8: 16, 9: 16}, 2: {0: 16, 1: 16, 2: 16, 3: 16, 4: 16, 5: 16, 6: 16, 7: 16, 8: 16, 9: 16}, 3: {0: 16, 1: 44, 2: 80, 3: 42, 4: 71, 5: 28, 6: 14, 7: 28, 8: 42, 9: 81}}
```

This extends for 8000 rows.

This is as far as I've gotten. My goal for example would be to say something like "for every instance of '42' in column 3, delete that row"

Any help I can get is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Provide a sample of your DataFrame using `pddf.head(10).to_dict()` and the expected output.

Comment: I just updated the post with a screenshot and a description of what I'm looking for. This particular sequence only had 4 characters, equaling 4 columns. For the example I initially gave, that sequence would have 6 columns.

Comment: We can't re-create your data from screenshots. Use `pddf.head(10).to_dict()` like I mentioned. Is your current code working as needed? If not, what is your expected output?

Comment: [You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451)

Comment: I just updated with the expected output. Sorry for the formatting errors.